# What are the criteria of memory equivalency?

Tags: memory

What are the criteria of memory equivalency? There is an opinion that chips with the same model will work better (coexist together better). For example, let's consider concrete case of **typical situation** - user wants to upgrade memory:
Given 8 Gb memory and we can buy additional for (say DZ77GA-70K) up to the limit of 32 Gb - so 3 additional units each 8Gb.
**for all 4 units to be the same** there are **options**:

- We can buy 3 additional units marked as KVR16N11/8_KVR16N11H/8 and use them simultaneously with my current one marked as Part number 99U5471-039.A00LF.
- We buy 4 new units and spent some time and sell my current one.

We can encounter in Internet that this memory model marked as KVR16N11. So, is memory Kingston Part number 99U5471-039.A00LF equivalent to memory marked as KVR16N11/8_KVR16N11H/8 in this context? Is this intersection (KVR16N11 and KVR16N11/8_KVR16N11H/8) can be considered as the criteria of equivalency?

Comment: For what purpose?  If the purpose is to ensure proper dual/triple/quad channel operation, then the memory modules should be tested to confirm matching timing parameters.

Comment: for upgrade purpose. Are matching timing parameters sufficient criteria of optimal coexistence? Even if vendors differ?

Comment: to test I should have test results (unlikely) or test myself - it means I should buy and own memory - risky way. I need algorithm without testing.

Comment: The timing values are critical.  None of the timing should be greater than your existing memory chips.  They can be lower all they want, but not higher.  The memory frequency, 1866(eg), can be higher but not less.

Comment: So, if I satisfy timing values criteria then whether memory vendor of different chips is the same within one machine does not matter?